# Is it possible to exclude specific resolutions or define supported ranges on manifest?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've recently collected reports in one of my apps regarding
layout loading errors (xml-inflating error) and out of memory errors from 
devices such as the IS03 which have uncommon screen resolutions (eg. 960 x 640 ).
Taking into consideration that I havent found any workaround yet, is it possible 
to prevent devices such as IS03 to install my app? I can't abandon all hdpi devices
I just need a way to prevent devices having uncommon resolutions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> which have uncommon screen resolutions (eg. 960 x 640 )

There is no concept in Android of "common screen resolutions".

> is it possible to prevent devices such as IS03 to install my app?

No, sorry.